# Functional way to enumerate enumerable if it contains any items

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, ienumerable

I am simply looking for an alternative to

```
if (enumerable.Any())
{
   // Code to Map to new type.
}
```

I know that the foreach method in linq does this but it returns void and i require something that can pass the collection to a new type.

The problem I am trying to avoid is enumerating the collection twice and reducing cyclomatic complexity.

I was wondering if there are any existing methods in the linq library that would allow this.

Comment: You could `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`, but probably it isn't the response you want.

Comment: Do you mean `Select`? `enumerable.Select(item => new Whatever { SomeProperty = item.SomeProperty });`

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, what exactly is wrong with just running "Code to map to new type" directly? Are you aware of the `Select` method?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen as I said I want to avoid enumerating the collection twice and reduce cyclomatic complexity by using preexisting linq constructs.

Comment: @nbokmans this would optionally execute code on a none null collection rather i want something that optionally executes the select statement on a collection that has items.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, can you be a bit more specific

Comment: But why will .Select enumerate the collection twice? My suggestion was to avoid using .Any

Comment: If you see the implementation of Any https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6a1af7c3d17845e3 then you would observe that it don't enumerate all the items of collection. As soon as the first item is found (with provided predicate) it returns the appropriate flag.

Comment: @nbokmans oh sorry, I mistook the question mark as a null derefrencing operator. But another problem is that I require all the elements im the collection to be passed to the mapping function

Comment: You can also use `enumerable.ForEach(i => i.DoStuff());` if collection of type List<T>. But as suggested by @nbokmans `Select` would best fit as per your requirement.

Comment: I agree with other commenters. In most cases doing Any check is useless. Just do what you are going to without this check. If there are no items - you will get no results anyway.

Comment: `Select` processes all elements of the collection. I think you trying to make something very simple very hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConvertAll with a converter method that map your object to your new type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx

Exemple from MSDN

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<PointF> lpf = new List<PointF>();

        lpf.Add(new PointF(27.8F, 32.62F));
        lpf.Add(new PointF(99.3F, 147.273F));
        lpf.Add(new PointF(7.5F, 1412.2F));

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach( PointF p in lpf )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }

        List<Point> lp = lpf.ConvertAll( 
            new Converter<PointF, Point>(PointFToPoint));

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach( Point p in lp )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }

    public static Point PointFToPoint(PointF pf)
    {
        return new Point(((int) pf.X), ((int) pf.Y));
    }
}

/* This code example produces the following output:

{X=27.8, Y=32.62}
{X=99.3, Y=147.273}
{X=7.5, Y=1412.2}

{X=27,Y=32}
{X=99,Y=147}
{X=7,Y=1412}
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a similar problem... Then I created this:

```
// Simple IEnumerable<T> that "uses" an IEnumerator<T> that has
// already received a MoveNext(). "eats" the first MoveNext() 
// received, then continues normally. For shortness, both IEnumerable<T>
// and IEnumerator<T> are implemented by the same class. Note that if a
// second call to GetEnumerator() is done, the "real" IEnumerator<T> will
// be returned, not this proxy implementation.
public class EnumerableFromStartedEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
{
    public readonly IEnumerator<T> Enumerator;

    public readonly IEnumerable<T> Enumerable;

    // Received by creator. Return value of MoveNext() done by caller
    protected bool FirstMoveNextSuccessful { get; set; }

    // The Enumerator can be "used" only once, then a new enumerator
    // can be requested by Enumerable.GetEnumerator() 
    // (default = false)
    protected bool Used { get; set; }

    // The first MoveNext() has been already done (default = false)
    protected bool DoneMoveNext { get; set; }

    public EnumerableFromStartedEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, bool firstMoveNextSuccessful, IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Enumerator = enumerator;
        FirstMoveNextSuccessful = firstMoveNextSuccessful;
        Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (Used)
        {
            return Enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        Used = true;
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            // There are various school of though on what should
            // happens if called before the first MoveNext() or
            // after a MoveNext() returns false. We follow the 
            // "return default(TInner)" school of thought for the
            // before first MoveNext() and the "whatever the 
            // Enumerator wants" for the after a MoveNext() returns
            // false
            if (!DoneMoveNext)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return Enumerator.Current;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!DoneMoveNext)
        {
            DoneMoveNext = true;
            return FirstMoveNextSuccessful;
        }

        return Enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // This will 99% throw :-) Not our problem.
        Enumerator.Reset();

        // So it is improbable we will arrive here
        DoneMoveNext = true;
    }
}
```

and this

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, out IEnumerable<TSource> newSource)
    {
        var coll = source as ICollection<TSource>;

        if (coll != null)
        {
            newSource = source;
            return coll.Count != 0;
        }

        var coll2 = source as ICollection;

        if (coll2 != null)
        {
            newSource = source;
            return coll2.Count != 0;
        }

        var enu = source.GetEnumerator();

        bool success = enu.MoveNext();

        newSource = new EnumerableFromStartedEnumerator<TSource>(enu, success, source);

        return success;
    }
}
```

That you use like this:

```
var enu = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Where(x => x > 3);

IEnumerable<int> enu2;

Console.WriteLine(enu.Any(out enu2));

foreach (var num in enu2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

The basic idea is that you begin enumerating the `IEnumerable<>` and enumerate only the first element. Now you have a partially consumed `IEnumerator<T>`. Then you "package" this partially consumed `IEnumerator<T>` in a new `IEnumerable<T>` "correctly" built (the `enu2` of the example)... When this `IEnumerable<T>` is next consumed, it will return the partially consumed `IEnumerator<T>`, with some tricks to make it seem that it wasn't really consumed.

Comment: Does `coll.Count` not enumerate all items of `ICollection` to retrieve the count? If yes, then collection is being enumerated more than once.

Comment: @user1672994 I use `Count` if the source is a `ICollection`/`ICollection<T>`... There is normally a guarantee that objects that implement that interfaces "know" their number of elements without needing to enumerate them. You are thinking of `Enumerable.Count()`

Answer (score 0):

`Select` seems like the best option, but if your mapping is complicated and/or isn't generating a simple type, then you must be looping over the collection in the body of the `if`. In that case, you can just handle enumeration manually:

```
var e = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
if (e.MoveNext()) {
    // Code to Map to new type.
    do {
        // map e.Current to new type
    } while (e.MoveNext());
}
```